# How can I render painted image texture in cycles?

Tags: texture-painting

I want to paint a specific colour on a specific area of an image used as texture in cycles. I set it that so that it shows correctly in texture mode, but I cannot make it show in render mode. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Texture paint will only show in Cycles when saved and refreshed. Save the paint work to disk and then tab in and out of edit mode to refresh your render view, or press render again to get the update.